# Paypal Payer ID

Tags: python, paypal

I have several questions regarding to the Paypal payer ID

1. As a e-shop I would expecting returning customers, is it possible that I capture the payer id? I would like to provide extra convenience to the customer for not entering payment methods (similar to credit card). If I keep the payer id in my server, are there any legal issue?
2. I created the program based on [Paypal REST API reference](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/python?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox) (Python method). I created my own python program. But I got stuck on step 4 of 5.

> payer_id = ""   # Payer ID is collected from the Paypal. I filled in my number
>
> payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payer_id)
>
> **Response[404]: Not Found, Duration: 0.572563s**

I have no idea how to solve the 404 problem. Thanks for the help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the API call for the payer id, using the access token returning from PayPal?

Comment: I don't use the API call. Here is the steps I've done:
  1) Installed the python module
  2) Created two paypal account for paypal-paypal transfer
  3) Inserted money from the payer account
  4) Transferred money to payment receiver account, using the script in the link above

Comment: The API call is encapsulated from the python library.

Comment: When you say "I filled in my number" for payer id, each payer id is going to be unique each time. Meaning, even if I order from the site, twice my payer id will be different each time. So its imperative that the payer id is being called.